# Can I run an application inside Facebook iFrame without logging in?

Tags: php, facebook

I am going through a discussion and I need to know if we can have users operate on a Facebook Page tab application without logging into Facebook? I don't want any user info, I don't need to know if they liked it or not. I just want them to be able to use my iFrame App without having to log into Facebook.

For eg: Log out of Facebook and go to this page: https://www.facebook.com/nissancanada/app_331500170235929. You can still work on it without having to log into Facebook. So, can I have a similar page for forms and submit options without having the user to log into Facebook?

PS: Don't ask what's the point of having this etc. It is a long thought idea. Just trying to find something on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can (just like in the link you passed)... you don't need to do anything special... just don't ask for login and it will work.

though for some pages the properties of the page might prevent access to the page without active login so it is not depends on the application